# Finding current page number in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How can I find the current page number in jqGrid (using jQuery of course). Also how do I know how many pages are there in total.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$("#sp_1").text(); // total pages

$(".ui-pg-input").val(); // current page
```

**Edit:** I found a better way in the [docs](http://trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) for the current page but I didn't see anything for the total page count. [(Click Manipulating -> Get Methods)](http://trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

```
$('#your_grid').getGridParam('page'); // current page
```

Answer (score 5):

this is an old question but it might help someone,

```
$("#"+gridId).getGridParam('lastpage')
```

will give the last page, which is the total too.  Its useful to use firebug and

```
console.log($("#"+gridId).getGridParam());
```

which will show all the gridParams accessible.

Answer (score 2):

About last page in grid, the best way is to use jqGrid - docs.
In this case:

```
jQuery("#gridID").getGridParam('pgtext');
```

And if you have only 1 page, the result should be

```
"Page {0} of {1}"
```

from [jqGrid wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions):

> pgtext -> string -> Show information about current page status. The first value is the current loaded page. The second value is the total number of pages.

Another way is to get all records and divide to records on page:

```
var rowNum = jQuery("#gridID").getGridParam('rowNum');
var allRecords = jQuery("#gridID").getGridParam('records');
var totalPages = parseInt((allRecords / rowNum) + 1);
```