# How to get the page number from the JQGrid Paginator?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, pagination

I have JQGrid in my application. If i wanted to capture the user input from Pagination's page number text box, what i have to do? And also i wanted to do it before grid changes it's page.

Is there any way to do it? Please, somebody help me to implement this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349700/finding-current-page-number-in-jqgrid

Comment: i figured out using this post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [onPaging](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:pager#events) callback If is's needed you can event stop changing of the page. In case of direct user input the parameter of callback will be the string `"user"`. To get the current value you can use either `page` parameter or get or set the value directly from the input control

```
onPaging: function (pgButton) {
    var pagerId = this.p.pager.substr(1); // ger paper id like "pager"
    var newValue = $('input.ui-pg-input', "#pg_" + $.jgrid.jqID(pagerId)).val();
        // newValue is in the most cases the same as in this.p.page
        // only wrong values like -10 entered by user will not update
        // "page" parameter
    if (pgButton === "user" && newValue > 2) { // some tests
        return "stop";
    }
}
```

**UPDATED:** [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) don't have the described above problem. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-callbacks-and-jQuery-events#changesenhancements-of-onpaging-callback) which describes additional `options` parameter of `onPaging` callback, which has `newPage`, `currentPage` and some other properties.

Comment: Thanks Oleg: might be good to have an "official" function like a jqGrid().getParam("userPage") for this sort of thing

Comment: @IcedDante: Starting with end of 2014 I develop my fork of jqGrid under the name [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). Already the first release of it (free jqGrid 4.8) had the feature described in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-callbacks-and-jQuery-events#changesenhancements-of-onpaging-callback). The `onPaging` callback have now the second parameter `options` which properties provides all information which could be needed. The current version from GitHub have more features. I plan to publish free jqGrid 4.9 soon.

Comment: The wiki update with the options param worked a treat.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem. I need to pass page number manually.
I found this code from another post I dont remeber :p.

Hope it will be help full

```
$("#GridId").getGridParam('page')
```